# How can I return Observable of IEmployees with productName from allProducts$ in RXJS?

Tags: rxjs

I want to return Observable from GetEmployeeByID function that has a matching productName from allProducts$:

```
allProducts$ = this.state$.pipe(
map(x => x.allProducts as IProducts[] || [] as IProducts[]),
distinctUntilChanged()); 

GetEmployeeByID(Id: number): Observable<IEmployees> {
  return this.allEmployees$.pipe(
    map(res => <IEmployees>res.find(data => data.id === Id) ?? { id: -1, name: "N/A", email: "N/A", gender: "N/A", productid: -1, productName: "N/A" } as IEmployees),
    switchMap((Employee: IEmployees) => {
       return this.allProducts$.subscribe(allProducts => {
        return of({
          ...Employee,
          productName: allProducts.find(Product => Product.productid == Employee.productid)?.name
        }) as IEmployees
       })
    })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of subscribing `allProducts$` inside `switchMap`, pipe through it, do what you need inside the pipe, and return its resulting observable. See the code below for context.

```typescript
class Foo {
  allProducts$ = this.state$.pipe(
    map(x => <IProducts[]> (x.allProducts ?? [])),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );
  
  public GetEmployeeByID(Id: number): Observable <IEmployees> {
    return this.allEmployees$.pipe(
      map(res => <IEmployees> res.find(data => data.id === Id) ?? {
        id: -1,
        name: "N/A",
        email: "N/A",
        gender: "N/A",
        productid: -1,
        productName: "N/A"
      }),
      switchMap((Employee: IEmployees) => {
        return this.allProducts$.pipe(  //  pipe through `allProducts$`
          map((allProducts) => <IEmployees> ({
            ...Employee,
            productName: allProducts.find(Product => Product.productid == Employee.productid)?.name
          }))
        )
      })
    )
  }
}
```